# Date validation with switch command does not work

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm writing a simple function to validate a date. The problem is it seems that the switch operator does not match anything and the value of `maxDay` remains 0. If I use `if` statements I don't have any problem.

```
function validateDateFormat(day,month,year) {
    alert(month); // this was to ensure month was correct and it is!!
    var maxDay = 0;
    switch(month)
    {
        case 01 :     
        case 03 :
        case 05 :
        case 07 :
        case 08 :
        case 10 :
        case 12 : maxDay = 31; break;
        case 04 :
        case 06 :
        case 09 :
        case 11 : maxDay = 30; break;
        case 02 : if(year%4 == 0) maxDay = 29;
              else maxDay = 28;
              break;    
        //default : return " Invalid month -"; break;    
    }
    alert(maxDay);
    if(day > maxDay) {return " Invalid day -";}
    return "";    
}
```

Comment: Leap years don't occur every 4 years actually. Given the life of your application and dates you'll be validating that might not be important. Just thought you might like to know that they work in 400 year cycles so there can occasionally be an 8 year gap between leap years. See [Why Leap Years Are Used](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html)

Comment: It's working fine for me in Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect the root issue is that you're providing strings as the arguments to `validateDateFormat`. If so, then the behavior can definitely be different when using `if` than when using `switch`. For example, assume you were to write this:

```
var num = "9";
if (num == 9)
    alert("true");
```

This will alert `true` because `==` (double-equals) triggers coercion of the string in `num` to a number before performing the comparison. However, this will alert nothing:

```
var num = "9";
switch(num) {
    case 9: 
        alert("true");
        break;
}
```

...because `switch` uses the more strict `===` (triple-equals) operator, which does not perform type-coercion.

This, however, does alert `true`:

```
var num = "9";
switch(num) {
    case "9": // string
        alert("true");
        break;
}
```

...because we're now comparing strings.

So, to fix your code you need to either pass actual numbers, or modify the function to compare strings.

**Note:** The `switch` behavior is covered in [section 12.11 of the ECMAScript spec](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.11).

Comment: Thanks I just realized exactly that. I enter in a form Strings and not value integer. Thanks a lot, beginner mistake I guess... Oh well I am though. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickBouche you should accept the answer if it satisfied your question

Answer (score 0):

You should not prefix your numbers with a `0`; that causes the numeric literal to be interpreted as octal.  Since `08` is not a valid octal number, your script may be generating a runtime error.

Comment: Did you even try it? This is not the issue.

Comment: It seems to be working for me.  Since it's not for you, I figured you may be using a browser that doesn't handle the syntax error of your JS as easily.

Comment: Or perhaps what you're passing into the function is different.  You should add that to your post.

Comment: My guess is that this is the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing the function is actually receiving strings